# Change column values where it's zero at mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

EDIT:

The table is GIGANTIC! I could just make the backup, and try it locally, if it went fine i could replicate the same on the server, but as i said, the database has almost 500mb, it is indeed quite big. Thanks to those who helped me :)

I'd like to change the values from the column "inside_position" where the cell values is 0

```
update TABLE_NAME SET inside_position=100 where inside_position=0;
```

I can't mess this up, so I'll not set up the trial and error method for this one.

Hope you can help me.

```
|Product_ID||Product_Code||Inside_position|
|   403    ||   EH009KP  ||       0       |
|   503    ||   GHSJSKD  ||       0       |
|   603    ||   KANSDAS  ||       1       |
|   703    ||   KJNKANS  ||       0       |
|   803    ||   KJHEERF  ||       0       |
|   903    ||   NBVDHQE  ||       5       |
|   910    ||   PKMRQEM  ||       0       |
|   980    ||   990KMNJ  ||       0       |
-------------------------------------------
```

This table describes my problem, I want to change the ones with 0 to 100.

Comment: Ummm..... what's the problem here?

Comment: You are asking if this will work? If that's your question, just backup your table and try it either on the original or the backup

Comment: the statement is fine. just run it. :)

Comment: your query is right ,so what is the problem??what error do you get?

Comment: What's the data-type of `Inside_position`?

Comment: There's a site called [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) (made by StackOverflow user [Jake Feasel](http://stackoverflow.com/users/808921/jake-feasel)), that you can use to test SQL queries.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3216d/4

Comment: Just make sure you run it in a transaction. If something goes wrong you can always rollback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted is fine?

```
 update TABLE_NAME SET inside_position=100 where inside_position=0
```

If you're worried about it not working, why not just duplicate the data into a dummy table and then run the query on those, that way you know for sure it will work :)

Comment: Please, read my edit on the question :)
Thank you very much mattytommo

Comment: Ah I see, well to be honest it looks *fool-proof*, you should be fine. If you were still doubting things you could take the top 10/100 rows from that table and put them elsewhere, run the query on that and check the results for a cast iron guarantee, but as I say, looks fine to me :)